# Protocol of a packet

Tags: c, tcp, udp, protocols, packet

I'm programming  an offline packets decoding program in C under Windows 7 x86.

I wonder how it is possible to know packet protocol, either if it is `UDP` or `TCP`?

Comment: Unless you are required to write this for a class, I suggest extending (or using as-is) the excellent [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  If for some reason you can't use Wireshark to solve whatever problem you have, it can still be valuable to double-check your own work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can know by checking the IP packet header, there is a `Protocol` field in the packet header that is used to indicate the type of the packet according to its value :

- `1` is ICMP
- `6` is TCP
- `17` is UDP

and so on. More information on this is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)

**Edit:** Here's [the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers) of all the possible values for that field.

**P.S:**
I'm assuming IPv4 here, I don't know if things are the same with IPv6

Comment: IPv6 all the same, only difference is in the ip layer, in order to get the protocol type you have to follow different parsing, but the values are the same.

Comment: @Medardas I can't know for sure (I don't know how you capture your traffic). Also, as a suggestion, you may wanna look at a library like [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html)

Answer (score 2):

The protocol is available in the IP header. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)